# CSS Positioning is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, positioning

Here is my code

CSS

```
       h2
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 100px;
            top: 150px;
        }
        h1
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: 300px;
        }
```

HTML

```
    <h1>
        Heading for Fixed Position
    <h2>
        This is a heading with an absolute position</h2>
    </h1>
```

I'm new to CSS so was experimenting with positioning. I read some where

> An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is `<html>`:

If that is right then `This is a heading with an absolute position` message must be below the `Heading for Fixed Position` since h1 is the parent object and h2 being a absolute object must be positioned relative to h1. Please correct if I'm wrong.

Here is the JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/KXmgG/

Comment: _"since h1 is the parent object"_ It is not a parent object. As it gets closed without any tags inside it.

Comment: ok i just made h1 as parent object.Updated code have a look

Comment: Here Parent block is HTML body and thus the o/p. try nesting <h1> <h2> tags !

Comment: @VedantTerkar i already did that.h2 is nested inside h1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to explain you how positioning actually works, there are 4 types

- Static (Default)
- Relative
- Absolute
- Fixed

Static position is nothing but a normal flow of the document where elements render on after the another (Excluding floats)

Relative position is something special, which turns out to be a great power when used with position absolute. When you want to use top, left, bottom and right instead of margins, you need to assign `position: relative;` to that element, after doing so, top, left, right and bottom properties will work.

When you use `position: absolute;` it gets out of the document flow, so if you have an element called `div` width class `a`. Now if you assign `position: absolute;` to class `a`, it will get out of the document flow, so when you use `top: 0;` it will fly away to the top of the document. So in order to restrict it, **we wrap a container with** `position: relative;` so that when you use `position: absolute;`, it will be absolute to that particular element and not the entire document.

[**Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/jmANZ/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/jmANZ/1/)

Position fixed is entirely different, it is also out of the document flow as same as `position: absolute;` but the difference is that fixed positioned element cannnot be relative to any element, it has no contact whatsoever with any element, it is always calculated from the top, left, right and bottom of the window and not the element, also a fixed position element will flow as the user scrolls the document.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KXmgG/2/)

---

Coming to your answer, you are using fixed position and absolute position, both are out of the document flow, so they have no relation what so ever...

You are using `top: 300px;` for fixed position and `top:: 150px;` for absolute positioned element, so the fixed element will render below the absolute element, but when you try to scroll, your fixed element will scroll along where as `position: absolute;` element won't.

---

Edit as you commented

Go to w3c Validator and validate your document [here](http://validator.w3.org/check)

[image]

Comment: may be u misunderstood the question.The container is fixed and the content is absolute not the other way

Comment: ok....can u explain diff between http://jsfiddle.net/M8cuv/  and http://jsfiddle.net/yjJBE/  ..dat would solve my issue :)

Comment: @iBlue semantically, markup is wrong, h1 tag cannot hold another header tag, also you have two `::` before absolute (nothing to do with the semantics though but css is wrong too as well as HTML)

Comment: corrected the :: but thats hardly the issue.U have any relevant source that say h1 tag cannot hold another header tag

Answer (score 0):

"An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is :"

Yes but you dont have `position:relative` declared.

If you want you're parent transform you're html by this :

```
<div class="parent">
    <h1 class="child">blabla</h1>
    <h2 class="child">blabla</h2>
</div> <!-- end parent -->

<div class="relative">
    <h1>
        Heading for Fixed Position</h1>
    <h2>
        This is a heading with an absolute position</h2>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.relative{
    position:relative;
    }
```

JSFIDDLE with

```
position relative / fixed / absolute /]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KXmgG/1/

Comment: "An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static", i have fixed declared